# Is it possible to edit an embed resource file during runtime?

Tags: c#, .net

I really don't think it is possible on a reasonably easy way but I'm asking just in case. I'm working on Visual C# Express 2010. I want to do this because it would probably be the easiest way to make a trial version that expires after certain amount of runs. Maybe not very safe way, but don't need any more safety at the moment, just simplicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an assembly at runtime so you could embed the resource in that and then load it into your AppDomain.

Answer (score 0):

embedding a resource file would imply changing the assembly,
if this assembly is being executed 
I don't think what you want is possible

if you want is a trial system,
make a webservice and call a method `programCanRunInComputerWithMAC(mac:string):bool`
you'd call this when the application loads